# Html Select/Dropdown's list isn't directly underneath - it's offset by the scrollbar

Tags: html, list, google-chrome, iframe, dropdown

In a normal webpage this drop down list displays with the menu underneath by 0px, however when it's in an iFrame in a SharePoint website the drop down's list is offset, and the y axis offset is related to the pages scroll bar:

[image: enter link description here]

Only happens in Chrome not IE, <strike>can't test FF atm</strike> and doesn't happen in FF.

I've searched the CSS styles but I can't narrow it down, I think the parent SharePoint page is overriding it and am wondering has anyone else seen and solved this problem?

Like I said it works normally, but in an iFrame **only in a live SharePoint server** I get that wierd offset! It's a vanilla HTML Select:

```
    <div id="awsCertList">
            <div class="form-group">        
            <label class="control-label">AWS Certification: </label>
            <select id="awsCertChoice" name="awsCertChoice" class=""> 

                    <option value="1">AWS Cloud Practitioner</option>

                    <option value="2">AWS Alexa Skill Builder</option>

                    <option value="4">AWS Developer Associate</option>

                    <option value="6">AWS Solution Architect Professional</option>

                    <option value="7">AWS DevOps Professional</option>

                    <option value="8">AWS Security</option>

                    <option value="9">AWS Networking</option>

                    <option value="10">AWS Big Data</option>

                    <option value="11">AWS Machine Learning</option>

            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Update:**

Somehow when I uncheck and recheck this property, the list appears right below as expected:

```
.s4-wpcell, .s4-wpcell-plain, .s4-wpActive {
    vertical-align: top;
```

**Update 2:**

When I scroll and change the pages width that fixes it. I've been mucking around with Javascript on scroll events using the Chrome debugger on a live site. I can't reproduce it locally, even when I save the SharePoint page the dropdown behaves as expected with the list directly underneath.

Comment: I am also having a similar issue dealing with an iFrame and dropdown position when scrolling.

Comment: @jgabb is yours specific to SharePoint, or can we compare scenarios?

Comment: No, mine is not specific to sharepoint but I have a web app that contains an iFrame that points to another web app (different domain).

Comment: Have you found a fix for this yet?

Comment: @jgabb no I'll put a bounty on it tomorrow after the 48hr wait

Comment: The only way i've gotten it to work is by changing the Html Select tags in the iFrame source to jquery selectMenus. However, that's only because I have access to the source code to do this. Seems like SharePoint may be able to change it on their side

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll use a JavaScript dynamic div menu

Comment: We've experienced something similar when scrolling the top window and fixed it by changing any iframe's style value on scroll events. Seems like it resets the dropdown position as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using html, CSS and JavaScript and I found a great reference example.

The drop down is simulated with CSS and the menu items are LI tags.

```
dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 0 1px 5px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    max-height: 144px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 9
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer
} 
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li:active {
    background-color: #e2e2e2
}
```

[Ref](https://codepen.io/General-Dev/pen/JRjwPa)