# Dropdown menu not working in razor page .Net6 mvc app

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-5

I made a dropdown menu using bootstrap. It works perfectly fine when I load an HTML file in VScode. But it does not work when I use the same dropdown markup in .NET6 MVC app's .cshtml file. By "does not work" I mean when I click on dropdown arrow, dropdown menu does not appear.

Note: I have verified all required bootstrap files are linked.
Here is the markup below:

```html
      <div class="dropdown text-end ms-4 me-1">
        <a href="#" class="d-block link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" 
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="bi bi-person-circle" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1" style="">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Orders</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Address</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
          </li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Are you running the page in a browser? What are you seeing?

Comment: @MikeBrind By "does not work" I mean when I click on dropdown arrow, dropdown menu does not appear.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the browser console? Viewed the source code? By the way, it works fine for me if I simply copy and paste your code into a Razor page/view.

Comment: Yes, I checked. there are no errors in the console and source code.

Comment: Probably be quicker to use a different implementation, here's a DropDownList out of HTML and CSS that solved one of my issues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59959177/495455

Comment: Hi @Mahnoor, it can work fine in my ASP.NET 6 project. How do you add the js reference in your project? Pls check if you have add bootstrap.js reference, also be sure the bootstrap version is 5.x.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I just found that my file referenced default bootstrap.js files added by IDE  itself. I removed that and now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused as the default link to local files of bootstrap was also added. Hence, my layout page was linking to both bootstrap CDN and defaulted bootstrap link when the MVC app is created. I removed the link to local bootstrap file that solved the problem.